# MySQL cursor not exit in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hell sir, 
I have used cursor for fetching data from one my table. After fetching data from cursor , I insert data another table. Problem is that it continue inserting data not exit.That means it is continue inserting.....
Here is my code used in stored procedure.

```
  DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT customercode,productid
    FROM dt_products;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;


    OPEN cur1;
       LOOPROWS:
         LOOP
           FETCH cur1  INTO v_customer_id, v_productid;
           IF done = 1
           THEN
              LEAVE LOOPROWS;
           END IF;

           INSERT INTO orders(ORDER_ID, mailid)
           VALUES (v_customer_id, v_productid);
        END LOOP LOOPROWS;
     CLOSE cur1
```

Please help me...

Comment: This code segment works fine and exists as expected. If you are still having an issue I suggest you post sample data as text to the question and include all your procedure code from the create begin to end;

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks it is working fine now.